# Common mode range?

Tags: operational-amplifier, common-mode

I managed finding the \$A_{cm},A_d\$ both in b and c (both sections yielded \$A_d=1,A_{cm}=0\$), but I have no idea how to determine the limitation on the range of the input common-mode signal and would appreciate some help with that.
[image]

Comment: Should my question be phrased differently in order for someone to try and assist? Did I formulate it inadequately?

Comment: The op amp common mode input voltage  is Vcm = (Vb + Va)/2  and differential input voltage Vid = Vb - Va

Comment: @G36 so based on your answer, wouldn't the common mode range be +-2.5V?

Comment: But they ask about the Vi1 and Vi2 input.

Comment: Or simply assume Vb = Va = 2.5V  and solve for Vi1 and Vi2

Comment: @G36 I get +-5V, does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, good for you. For Vin = 5V we have Va = Vb = 2.5V, so Vcm = (2.5+2.5V)/2 = 5V/2 = 2.5V